# sort by names in a list in ascending order onclick with angularjs

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

I populate brief info about customers in a table from a web api. What i want to achieve is when someone should click on the `Customer Name` text, the names there should be order in ascending order and on another click it should toggle to descending. By default when the page loads it arranges the list by ID descending

HTML

```
<table class="table table-striped table-hover">
  <tr class="success">
    <td><strong><a href="#">Customer Name</a></strong></td>
    <td><strong>Phone Number</strong></td>
    <td><strong>Address</strong></td>
    <td><strong>Gender</strong></td>
    <td><strong>Email</strong></td>
    <td><strong>User Group</strong></td>
  </tr>
  <tr ng-repeat="item in users_list | orderBy:'-ID'">
    <td>{{item.Customer_Name}}</td>
    <td>{{item.Phone_Number}}</td>
    <td>{{item.Address}}</td>
    <td>{{item.gender}}</td>
    <td>{{item.email}}</td>
    <td>{{item.user_group}}</td>
  </tr>
  </table>
```

JS

```
.controller('app_users_ctrl',function($scope,$http,$location){
    $scope.loading=true;
    $http.post('http://localhost/calls/app_users.php').success(function(data){
    $scope.users_list=data
    console.log(JSON.stringify(data));
    $scope.loading=false;
        })
    })
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hi have you tired something like:

```
<table class="table table-striped table-hover">
  <tr class="success">
    <td><strong><a clikme('Customer_Name')>Customer Name</a></strong></td>
    <td><strong><a clikme('Phone_Number')>Phone Number</a></strong></td>
    <td><strong>Address</strong></td>
    <td><strong>Gender</strong></td>
    <td><strong>Email</strong></td>
    <td><strong>User Group</strong></td>
  </tr>
  <tr ng-repeat="item in users_list | orderBy: myvar">
    <td >{{item.Customer_Name}}</td>
    <td >{{item.Phone_Number}}</td>
    <td>{{item.Address}}</td>
    <td>{{item.gender}}</td>
    <td>{{item.email}}</td>
    <td>{{item.user_group}}</td>
  </tr>
  </table>
```

and the in you js:

```
.controller('app_users_ctrl',function($scope,$http,$location){
    $scope.loading=true;
    var order = false;

$http.post('http://localhost/calls/app_users.php').success(function(data){
    $scope.users_list=data
    console.log(JSON.stringify(data));
    $scope.loading=false;
        })
    })

$scope.clikme= function(field){

 $scope.myvar= order ? '-' + field : '+' + field;
order=!order;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.4/angular.min.js"></script>
<body>

<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="orderCtrl">

<ul>
<li ng-repeat="x in cars | orderBy">{{x}}</li>
</ul>

</div>

<script>
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);
app.controller('orderCtrl', function($scope) {
    $scope.cars = ["Dodge", "Fiat", "Audi", "Volvo", "BMW", "Ford"];
});
</script>

<p>The array items are displayed alphabetically.</p>

</body>
</html>
```

As I don't have your JSON data, I added a simple example of sorting in ascending order. All we have to do is, use orderBy filter.

Answer (score 0):

Suppose You are storing your fields in values array so for ascending order and onclick:

```
values.sort(function(value1,value2){ return value2 - value1; });
```

For decending order:

```
values.sort(function(value1,value2){ return value1 - value2; });
```

Hope it helps.
Also Use a flag inside your function to take care of order in which it is sorted.

Answer (score 0):

https://scotch.io/tutorials/sort-and-filter-a-table-using-angular

Follow that guide. It helped me when I had to do what you have to do!

Answer (score 0):

This is a simple example of using table in angularJS with sorting anf filter

```js
angular.module("myApp", ["ngTable"]);


//This is your controller

var self = this;
var data = [{name: "Deon", age: 22} /*,*/];
self.tableParams = new NgTableParams({}, { dataset: data});
```

```html
<table ng-table="vm.tableParams" class="table" show-filter="true">
    <tr ng-repeat="user in $data">
        <td title="'Name'" filter="{ name: 'text'}" sortable="'name'">
            {{user.name}}</td>
        <td title="'Age'" filter="{ age: 'number'}" sortable="'age'">
            {{user.age}}</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

It's easy, add ng-click="sortType == 'customer-name'" or whatever else you'd like to sort by, on each table heading. BTW, you should fix your table and use thead > th for headings. It's the proper way of formatting it.